# How can Java access COM control (on windows platform) APIs

Tags: java

I have a COM control (on windows) that exposes a set of APIs. I have written applications in VC++ and C# and can access the APIs. Now I need to write a Java application that will use those COM APIs. Could you let me know how can I do that? Do I need to write a Java wrapper for the COM control (like JNI)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Jacob.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

I had to access COM controls from inside of Java, and Jacob totally saved my bacon.